# Need help understanding IC Behavior

Tags: integrated-circuit

I built a circuit based on this IC. 
Link: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/256/MAX756-MAX757-92691.pdf

It says if you put the 2nd pin to Low, then it switches to 5 v out. That seems to be untrue. I found that if you float the pins and then touch a finger to the 1st pin, then it switched to 5 v. I can also touch it with a jumper wire, paper clip, and also hoover my finger over the pin and it jumps from 3 v to 5 v.

What is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps its your construction - try placing a pull up resistor of say, 4k7, from pin 2 to out (pin 6) and then you can ground pin 2 without shorting the output.

Comment: Quick question: Could I use a 10k Ohm resistor instead of 4.7k?

Comment: Yes, its just a pull up. The input takes next to no current so the value isn't critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the datasheet:

> ```
> Control-Logic Inputs
> The control inputs (3/5, SHDN) are high-impedance
> MOS gates protected against ESD damage by normally
> reverse-biased clamp diodes. If these inputs are driven
> from signal sources that exceed the main supply 
> voltage, the diode current should be limited by a series
> resistor (1MΩ suggested). The logic input threshold
> level is the same (approximately 1V) in both 3.3V and
> 5V modes. Do not leave the control inputs floating.
> ```

Sounds like you left the control input floating, in violation of the explicit direction in the datasheet, which leaves the CMOS input in a high impedance state, susceptible to nearby electric fields (like those created by the charge stored on your finger). In essence, the behavior is unpredictable in this condition.

Comment: Interesting. You could place a 5v circuit on the other end and do all sorts of things with this. If you place a jumper on it the other end acts like an antenna. Detects the presence of the finger from about 2 inches.

Comment: Yes, all sorts of unpredictable things :-)